# Generate ID based on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was desperately trying to find this issue here, but could not find anything related to this question.

In SQL (SMSS), I want to have an ID column. Values for the ID should be generated based on 3 columns in the same table.

```
ID | column1 | column2 | column3
1  | 2016    | 101     | 1
2  | 2017    | 101     | 1
2  | 2017    | 101     | 1
3  | 2017    | 303     | 1
```

Can anyone help me to have this ID generated?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Are `col1` + `col2` + `col3` are unique? Why autoincrement is not good for you?

Comment: @Justinas In the sample data, the second and third rows have the same values...

Comment: no they are not unique, therefore no autoincrement

Comment: @Buglkrax I've edited my answer. Please read again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, please note that having duplicate rows in a database table is not a good idea. **Rows in a database table should be unique.**

However, this doesn't mean that your table only contains these columns - it might very well contain other columns that are simply irrelevant to your question, so here goes:

Use [`DENSE_RANK()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql).

First, Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    column1 int,
    column2 int,
    column3 int
)

INSERT INTO @T (column1, column2, column3) VALUES
(2016, 101, 1),
(2017, 101, 1),
(2017, 101, 1),
(2017, 303, 1)
```

The query:

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Column1, Column2, Column3) AS ID,
       Column1,
       Column2,
       Column3
FROM @T
```

Results:

```
ID  Column1 Column2 Column3
1   2016    101     1
2   2017    101     1
2   2017    101     1
3   2017    303     1
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! I see your note about having redundant sets of data but as you mentioned: my table contains other columns  as well and I just found it irrelevant to mention in this context.
Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Glad to help :-).