# Generating increment identifiers for group of sequence values

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-order-by

In SQL:
I have a table similar to this

| ID | Name | Room |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | A |
| 2 | John | A |
| 3 | John | B |
| 4 | John | A |
| 5 | John | C |
| 6 | John | C |
| 7 | Nick | C |
| 8 | Nick | B |
| 9 | Nick | B |
| 10 | Nick | A |
| 11 | Nick | A |
| 12 | Nick | B |

I need to create an auto increasing `ID` where it follows the order of two columns `Name` and `Room`. If the order changes, the number increases.

The result should be something like this

| ID | Name | Room | New ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | A | 1 |
| 2 | John | A | 1 |
| 3 | John | B | 2 |
| 4 | John | A | 3 |
| 5 | John | C | 4 |
| 6 | John | C | 4 |
| 7 | Nick | C | 5 |
| 8 | Nick | B | 6 |
| 9 | Nick | B | 6 |
| 10 | Nick | A | 7 |
| 11 | Nick | A | 7 |
| 12 | Nick | B | 8 |

Could you please help?

Comment: Try the suggested solution in this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49551754/generate-id-based-on-multiple-columns

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `lag()` to see where a value changes.  Then use a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_id = prev_id_2 then 0 else 1 end) over (order by id) as newid
from (select t.*,
             lag(id) over (order by id) as prev_id,
             lag(id) over (partition by name, room order by id) as prev_id_2
      from t
     ) t;
```

The way this works is to look at the previous id and the previous id based on the `name` and `room`.  If these are the same, then there is no change.